# How can I remotely wipe a stolen phone?

Tags: security, lost-phone

My phone have been stolen and I have many pictures on it, and secret things! How can I trash every thing on it through a Whatsapp message? I have not tired anything yet.

Answer (score -2):

if you have android device manager then login to android device manager through your PC, the rest you can control it from there :-)